# Reading and Storing Integer from Serial Monitor

Tags: c++, beginner, integer, serialization, arduino

### Description

I wanted to understand how integers can be written and stored inside variables without the use of Serial.parseInt(). I couldn't find any code examples about this. Perhaps this is the right way to do it, although it doesn't detect and block letters and special characters. Please leave some feedback on ways to improve it. Thanks in advance! :)

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600); // Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  Serial.println(F("Serial port opened!"));
}

void loop()
{
  byte received;
  static byte counter = 0;
  static uint32_t number = 0; // Store value from 0 to 4294967295

  while (Serial.available()) // Read data in serial receive buffer
  {
    received = Serial.read(); // Store received byte
    if (received != 10) // Terminate if newline char detected
    {
      if (counter != 0) // Put number in its correct position (base-10 system)
      {
        number *= 10;
        number += (received - '0');
      }
      else
      {
        number = (received - '0');
      }
      counter++;
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println(number); // Print value inside number and reset
      counter = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Character literals

While this is technically correct:

```
if (received != 10) // Terminate if newline char detected
```

you're better off writing

```
if (received != '\n')
```

Much of embedded electronics assumes ASCII encoding, and this is no exception, but you're still better off using the symbol instead of the code.

### IO management

You loop while serial I/O is available:

```
while (Serial.available())
```

But what if there is a pause in the availability of bytes in the middle of your integer? Your code will not do the right thing. Instead:

```
uint32_t number = 0;
while (true) {
  int received = Serial.read();
  if (received == -1) continue;
  if (received == '\n') break;
  // ...
}
Serial.println(number);
```

- Do not use `static` for `number`
- Don't need a `counter`
- Keep looping if no data are available
- Ensure that one execution of `loop` maps to one full output integer

### Condition in loop

If you are using the ATmega328P, it has a dedicated `MUL` instruction that only takes two cycles. It's more complex and expensive to have your `if (counter != 0)` than it is to simply unconditionally multiply-and-add.

Comment: Re: "Do not use static for number
Don't need a counter" ==> OP looks like `loop()` is a service function, not always called when data first arrives, but as it arrives.  OP's approach is OK in that case.  A non-global alternative would pass in the state data.

Comment: Minor: to be _technically correct_, `'\n'` is an _integer constant_, not a _character literal_.  C does define _string literals_ and _compound literals_, but no other _literals_.  Perhaps you are thinking of another language?

Comment: Re. statics - it's a common micro-optimization in embedded code to make a function non-reentrant by switching local variables to `static`; and technically `loop` is a "service" function that's called by the Arduino firmware and does not need to be re-entrant. However, such an optimization is premature, and statics are a bad idea to invoke unless thoroughly justified.

Comment: Also, there is no correlation between the arrival of data and the timing of a `loop` call.

Comment: Also also, to be _technically correct_ (the best type of correct), this is not C, nor is it even C++ - it's "Wiring", which is a dialect of C++.

Comment: @chux Finally - many, many sources (take your pick, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_literal or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal come to mind) explicitly describe character literals in C++; and certainly C++ has more of a character literal than (say) Python, which only has length-one strings.

Comment: As the post was originally tagged C, implying the OP wanted a C review,  the source I used was the C spec. There is nothing about OP code that would not compile in C.  As to if the code review was to be based on another language, best to ask OP.

Comment: _There is nothing about OP code that would not compile in C_ - well, `Serial` is a class. So not nothing.

Comment: In C, a `struct` can have members that are functions pointers and look just like `Serial.begin(9600);`

Comment: Sure, but "look just like" is a theoretical, and this is a concrete reference to something that's in the Wiring library, which is definitely not using a `struct`. It doesn't matter if this "can be" C code when it is certainly C++ code.

Comment: As a beginner this all looks like Chinese to me! I tried to stick to C as much as possible as my knowledge about C++ is even less. Would it be possible to execute a function if data arrived in the 'Serial' buffer (without using a loop)?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/106684

Answer (score 2):

For more robust code to detect non-numeric input, overflow and start-up phasing, consider a [state machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647631/c-state-machine-design/1647679#1647679).

```
typedef struct {
  int counter;  // <0:indeterminate, 0:spacing, >0:digits; 
  uint32_t number;
} loop_state;

// Quietly drop data in 3 cases:
// 1) Overflow
// 2) Non-numeric
// 3) When state is indeterminate
void loop(loop_state *state) {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    byte received = Serial.read(); // Store received byte
    if (received >= '0' || received <= '9') { // or isdigit((unsigned char) received)
      if (state->counter >= 0) {
        state->counter++;
        unsigned digit = received - '0';
        if (state->number >= UINT32_MAX / 10
            && (state->number > UINT32_MAX / 10 || digit > UINT32_MAX % 10)) {
          // overflow
          state->counter = -1;
          continue;
        }
        state->number = state->number * 10 + digit;
      }
    } else if (isspace((unsigned char) received)) {
      if (state->counter == 1) {
        Serial.println(state->number);
      }
      state->number = 0;
      state->counter = 0;
    } else {
      state->number = 0;
      state->counter = -1;
    }
  }
}
```